# Get center of SVG path and VML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, vml

I'm trying out different things with:

- https://jvectormap.com/

I'm very much interested in getting the center of the different countries (so I can place a little marker on the country).

But I'm kinda struggling with it and I've tried several things, such as getting the surrounding box of a path and then getting the center from that.

But it sort of fails due to some shapes of certain countries. For example USA where the middle of the surround box is in Canada.

Answer (score 1):

Just given the SVG data provided by the URL it's computationally impossible to find out what part of USA (or any other country) to consider the main/central part.

An approximate solution would be to count the largest fillable area as the main area and calculate the center of this area. Unfortunately the SVG API provides no method for area calculations.

What you are left with is the possibility to iterate over each separate path segment, calculate their individual lengths and implement a good enough approximation algorithm for finding the center of the main part. Be aware that only "lineto", "curveto" and "arcto" commands are part of the total path length which you can get by invoking `.getTotalLength()` on the path element.

A really primitive code skeleton:

```
var getCenterOfCountry = function (path) {

  var posX, posY, i, ii, seg;

  posX = 0;
  posY = 0;

  for (i=0, ii=path.pathSegList.numberOfItems; i<ii; i++) {

    seg = path.pathSegList.getItem(i);

    switch (seg.pathSegTypeAsLetter) {
      case 'z':
      case 'Z':
        // handle case close path, update pos
        break;
      case 'M':
        // handle case moveto abs, update pos
        break;
      case 'm':
        // handle case moveto rel, update pos
        break;

      // ... handle all remaining cases, remember to update pos

      default:
        // handle case path segment unknown
    }
  }
};
```

Invoke like:

```
var usPath, usCenterCoords;

usPath = document.querySelector('#jvectormap1_us');
usCenterCoords = getCenterOfCountry(usPath);
```